# how to create custom middleware in node using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, middleware

I am having trouble from middle-ware that is not giving response. I have searched for this problem but couldn't find the applicable solution to resolve this issue.

#### How I'm doing to create the middelware

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use(function log(req, res, next) {
    console.log('logging with fun...');
    next();
});

console.log('Help help help ...');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

Kindly guide, where I am making mistake because I am only getting output in the console as follows:

**Help help help ...**

**Listening on port: 3000**

Comment: Are you doing a request to localhost:3000?  Because you should, and it's expected to work.

Comment: Thanks, that was the case. I hadn't requested to localhost:3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added middleware correctly but you didn't create any route.

> Your code will become

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use(function log(req, res, next) {
    console.log('logging with fun...');
    next();
});

// Just add any route.
app.get('/',function log(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello');
});

console.log('Help help help ...');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

> Now navigate to `http://localhost:3000/`